# Cloudflare Nginx HTTPS proxy_pass every path

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup https using nginx and cloudflare. I generated a certificate and key using cloudflare and added them to my nginx config (See below).

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <URL_HIDDEN>;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/own-certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/own-certs/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header UPgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem: Only the main page works (`/`).
When going to **any** other page (Like `/favicon.ico`), I'm getting a 504 error after 30 seconds. When using the specific port and same path (`http://localhost:8082/favicon.ico`), everything works fine. Everything works fine when I remove the ssl part too.

It isn't a nginx timeout issue, because I'm getting a response within 5ms when using the localhost URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. change nginx config (Also necessary if you already enabled "always https"):

```
server {
    listen 80; # ADD THIS

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <URL_HIDDEN>;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/own-certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/own-certs/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header UPgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

2. set cloudflare setting:
   [image: cf1]
3. enable always use https:
   [image: cf2]

Comment: I already enabled `Always Use HTTPS` more than a year ago. 
But when I added the `listen: 80;` part, everything worked, even though everything goes though https and not http (I double checked).